UseEffect cleanup in socket.io-client
useEffect(() => {
  if (authUser) {
    const socket = io("http://localhost:5000", {
      query: {
        userId: authUser._id,
      },
    });

    setSocket(socket);

    socket.on("getOnlineUsers", (users: string[]) => {
      setOnlineUsers(users);
    });

    // the error disappeared when removing this line
    return () => socket.close();

  }
  else {
    if (socket) {
      socket.close();
      setSocket(null);
    }
  }
}, [authUser, socket]);


I got this weird error stating
Argument of type '() => (() => Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>) | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type '(() => Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'.
    Type '() => Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'.
      Type '() => Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>' is not assignable to type 'Destructor'.
        Type 'Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>' is not assignable to type 'void | { [UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY]: never; }'

I don't fully understand the error. Would someone be kind enough to help me with this, please? Thank you in advance.

This is the type of the callback inside useEffect. The return value from useEffect callbacks should either be
1: a function that returns type void


or a Destructor which are also allowed to only return void.


But socket.close which is a synonym of socket.disconnect returns a Socket instance.
Since arrow functions (without braces) simplicity return the expression inside, you can wrap it in curly braces to remove the TS error:
return () => {
socket.close();
}


No worries. Please accept the answer to complete this question
